# Poor Performance and Strange Array Behavior when run on Linux

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, video-processing

So I am working on a script to do some video processing. It will read a video file searching for red dots that are a certain size then find the center of each and return the x/y coordinates. Initially I had it working great on my Windows Machine, so I sent it over to the raspberry pi to see if i would encounter issues, and boy did I.

On Windows the script would run in real time, completing at the same time as the video. On the Raspberry it is slowwwwwwww. Also I noticed when I looked into the structure of countours, there is a huge array of 0's first, before my x/y coordinates array. I have no idea what is creating this, but it doesn't happen on the windows box.

I have same version of python and opencv installed on both boxes, the only difference is numpy 1.11 on windows and numpy 1.12 on raspberry. Note, I had to change np.mean(contours[?]) to 1 to skip the initial array of 0's. What have I done wrong?

Here's a video I made for testing purposes if needed:
http://www.foxcreekwinery.com/video.mp4

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def vidToPoints():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, image = cap.read()


        if (ret):

            cv2.imshow('frame',image)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break   

            # save frame as image
            cv2.imwrite('frame.jpg',image)

            # load the image
            image = cv2.imread('frame.jpg')

            # define the list of boundaries
            boundaries = [
                ([0, 0, 150], [90, 90, 255])
            ]

            # loop over the boundaries
            for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
                # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
                lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
                upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")

            # find the colors within the specified boundaries
            mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

            if (50 > cv2.countNonZero(mask) > 10):
                #find contour
                contours = cv2.findContours(mask, 0, 1)
                #average countour list to find center
                avg = np.mean(contours[1],axis=1)
                x = int(round(avg[0,0,0]))
                y = int(round(avg[0,0,1]))

                print [x,y]
                print cv2.countNonZero(mask)
                for l in range(5):
                    cap.grab()

        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

vidToPoints()
```

Comment: Have you considered that a Raspberry Pi is a much slower machine than a typical Windows machine?

Comment: I have, but the resource monitor is showing only 30% peak cpu usage. Is there something I am doing that is so resource intensive? Also that huge array that is being added has me concerned that there is something big going on that I don't understand. Why is there a huge array being added to contours on the raspberry that doesn't happen on windows?

Comment: A peak CPU usage on your Pi of only 30% is not "poor performance".  It seems to me that the real problem is something to do with I/O on the Pi.  (And that's not surprising either ... )  Also, have you tried profiling the application on both Pi and Windows and comparing.